# Jest: node_module dependency uses import statement and crashes the test

Tags: typescript, import, jestjs, syntax-error, next.js

### TL;DR

My Jest test crashes with

```
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

because a `node_module` uses an `import` statement. How can I fix this error?

### Context

I'm writing a Next.js app, use Jest as my test runner and [Magic](http://magic.link/) for authentication. I have `ts-node` installed to run my Jest tests in TypeScript.

I want to test a serverless function that uses the `@magic-sdk/admin` package, which in turn uses [ethereum-cryptography](https://github.com/ethereum/js-ethereum-cryptography) for its keccak hash algorithm.

When I run the test it crashes because the `ethereum-cryptography` package uses an `import` statement.

```
 FAIL  src/features/user-authentication/login-handler.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    /Users/my-computer/dev/my-app/node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/src/keccak.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { createHashFunction } from "./hash-utils";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/ethereum-cryptography/src/keccak.ts:3:26)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.292 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

My `tsconfig.json` is

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"]
}
```

My `jest.config.ts` looks like this.

```
export default {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/mocks/style-mock.js',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/setup-environment-variables.js'],
};
```

### What I Tried

It looks like this is a common error with tons of Google results, but none of them worked. Here is what I tried.

I tried including the folder in `transformIgnorePatterns`.

```
const esModules = ['ethereum-cryptography', '@magic-sdk/admin'].join('|');

export default {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/mocks/style-mock.js',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/setup-environment-variables.js'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: [`/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`],
};
```

It did not work.

I tried explicitly transforming it using `transform` and `ts-jest`.

```
transform: { '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)?$': 'ts-jest' },
```

I also tried changing the module to `commonjs` in the `tsconfig.json`, which didn't work either.

How can I fix this and get the test to run?

Comment: Current version of `@magic-sdk/admin` has no mention of ethereum-cryptography. Both packages have entry points that cannot cause such problem so it's unknown why it's there. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem, this includes exact package versions and all the code that is responsible for this import. You should do the opposite and prevent anything to be imported from src, there should preferably be no custom transformIgnorePatterns because transpiling a package that doesn't belong to you is a rabbit hole.

Comment: @EstusFlask `@magic-sdk/admin` uses Ethereum utils which in turn use the `ethereum-cryptograhy` package. Okay will create a codesandbox 

Comment: Basically, you need to find out at which point modules start to import from /src/ instead of compiled files and fix this with moduleNameMapper or else.

Comment: this is not an Ethereum question, it is a Javascript question. remove the "ethereum" tag

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it outside of Next.js projects   Really weird.

Comment: @EstusFlask Here is a repository with the raw code example but for some reason it works ... https://github.com/janhesters/mcve-typescript-bug-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my error. My `jest.config.ts` had `src` in the `moduleDirectories` because I configured Next.js to support absolute imports.

```
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', 'src'], //  fails
```

When I changed it to be explicitly from the `rootDir` it worked

```
export default {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/src'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.(css|less)$': '<rootDir>/src/tests/mocks/style-mock.js',
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./jest.setup.ts'],
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/tests/setup-environment-variables.js'],
};
```

Comment: Glad you sorted it out. Notice that 'fails' is a snippet that has been already fixed

Comment: I had a similar error and my issue was conflicting `.babelrc` and `babel.config.js` files. Once I cleared that up, all good w/a similar setup to yours. Thanks for the excellent question + postmortem answer.